# What does this human drawing returned by git in terminal mean?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Git showed me this:

[image]

I made mistake of not having changed the branch to the correct branch before I started adding files and pushing them up. But that aside, what does this ASCII drawing of a human mean?

Comment: This is output when you tried to do something you are not allowed to do. There should also be a message telling you what. Are you using bitbucket?

Comment: yes, I pushed up changes to development by mistake. But what is this picture exactly?

Answer (score 5):

Everything prefixed with `remote:` is what the remote server answered. It looks like the admin of said server likes to bring their point across through ASCII art.

Comment: What exactly is this ASCII art?

Comment: @quantum231 It's a picture of a body guard wearing sunglasses, but it's made using letters/symbols

Comment: @quantum231: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art (first result from googling `define ascii art`).

Answer (score 5):

Looks like your upstream branch is protecting main branch with stable code only from random pushes.

It's standard practice to have one stable branch that can only be pushed to via pull requests, so no random pushes appear.

And what you are seeing is just custom message of admin of server which hosts the repository.

You need to create new branch, and commit all changes there and then create pull request. You may need to use `git reset` command which is able to revert changes from commits back to stage/index.

Comment: It's not protecting main, but `development`

Comment: What exactly is this ASCII art?

Comment: @quantum231 It's just art with done by using characters only